# Using rbind to append the results to a data frame in a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny, reactive, rbind

I'm new to Rshiny and I'm having problems displaying the results in a for-loop where all the iterations get appended into the same data frame. The below minimal example works fine in R Desktop:

```
df_total = data.frame()
for (i in 1:7){
  # vector output
  model <- i + 10
    
    # add vector to a dataframe
    df <- data.frame(model)
  df_total <- rbind(df_total,df)
}
```

But when I try to replicate this in Rshiny and display the results in a table I just get blank results. Here is the minimal example of the code I'm using in Rshiny:

```
rm(list=ls())


library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    
    #Add tabs to the Dashboard
    tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
                
                
                #for DT::dataTableOutput
                tabPanel("table1", DT::dataTableOutput("TableSample")),
    )
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  
  FinalTable <- reactive({
    
    df_total = data.frame()
    for (i in 1:7){
      # vector output
      model <- i + 10
      
      # add vector to a dataframe
      df <- data.frame(model)
      df_total <- rbind(df_total,df)
    }
    

    
  })  
  

  
  output$TableSample <- DT::renderDataTable(FinalTable(), extensions = 'Buttons', 
                                                     options = list(scrollX=TRUE, lengthMenu = c(5,10,15),
                                                                    paging = TRUE, rownames = FALSE, searching = TRUE,
                                                                    fixedColumns = FALSE, autoWidth = FALSE,
                                                                    ordering = TRUE, dom = 'tB',
                                                                    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel','pdf')))                                        
  
  

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have try the suggestions posted [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737426/r-shiny-error-with-rbind-to-compile-results-from-a-loop-error-evaluation-neste).

I tried to use an observer to bind the reactive output in the for-loop. Tried several different approaches but nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add df_total to be the return of reactive FinalTable, like this :

```
   FinalTable <- reactive({
      
      df_total = data.frame()
      for (i in 1:7){
         # vector output
         model <- i + 10
         
         # add vector to a dataframe
         df <- data.frame(model)
         df_total <- rbind(df_total,df)
      }
      df_total
      
      
   })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response. That worked perfectly. Cheers